# How do you find out which view was tapped in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

So if I make a tap gesture recogniser in SwiftUI, like this...

```
@State var tapped = false

var tap: some Gesture {
    TapGesture(count: 1)
        .onEnded {
            _ in self.tapped = !self.tapped
            print("tapped!")

    }

}
```

... and then add this tap gesture recogniser to programmatically created Views in a list, like so...

```
 List {
                // loop through all the posts and create a post view for each item
                ForEach(posts) { post in
                    PostView(post: post)
                    .gesture(self.tap)

                }
            }
```

... this works, the taps do register, but I can't figure out how to determine which view was tapped, so that I can use the tap to update a variable or call a function of the associated view.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the post being tapped using a `@State` property that stores the `selectedPost` as shown here. And update the `View` as I've done with the background.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

  var posts: [Post] = []
  @State private var selectedPost: Post?
  @State private var tapped = false

  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(posts) { post in
        PostView(post: post)
          .background(post == selectedPost ? Color.clear : Color.green)
          .onTapGesture {
            self.selectedPost = post
            self.tapped.toggle()
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer shows how to get the post, but the OP is looking for the way to get the tapped view, i.e the `Text` view that was tapped.